# Usage of DISTINCT in reversed int pairs duplicates elimination

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have a following question:

```
create table memorization_word_translation
(
    id           serial  not null
    from_word_id integer not null
    to_word_id   integer not null
);
```

This table stores pairs of integers, that are often in reverse order, for example:

```
35 36
35 37
36 35
37 35
37 39
39 37
```

Question is  - if I make a query, for example:

```
select * from memorization_word_translation
where from_word_id = 35 or to_word_id = 35
```

I would get

```
35 36
35 37
36 35  - duplicate of 35 36
37 35  - duplicate of 35 37
```

How is to use DISTINCT  in this example to filter out all duplicates even if they are reversed?
I want to keep it only like this:

```
35 36
35 37
```

Comment: You'll want to normalise (here: sort) your items. Either on insertion, or during the query, with something like `SELECT (CASE a <= b THEN (a, b) ELSE (b, a) END) FROM …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
select from_word_id, to_word_id
from (
  select *,
         row_number() over (
           partition by least(from_word_id, to_word_id), 
                        greatest(from_word_id, to_word_id)
           order by (from_word_id > to_word_id)::int
         ) rn                                                         
  from memorization_word_translation 
  where 35 in (from_word_id, to_word_id)
) t
where rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c77160980d8066cfc836c3d41d2a2671).

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c1ba7ad525afc0badecd640d4f622458)

You could try a it with a small sorting algorithm (here a comparison) in combination with `DISTINCT ON`.

The `DISTINCT ON` clause works an arbitrary columns or terms, e.g. on a tuple. This CASE clause sorts the two columns into tuples and removes tied (ordered) ones. The source columns can be returned in your SELECT statement:

```
select distinct on (
    CASE 
        WHEN (from_word_id >= to_word_id) THEN (from_word_id, to_word_id)
        ELSE (to_word_id, from_word_id)
    END 
)
    * 
from memorization_word_translation
where from_word_id = 35 or to_word_id = 35
```